# OkHTTP connection to PayPal gives an SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm using Java 1.7 (jdk1.7.0_80_64x) and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

To connect to Paypal via this code...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.squareup.okhttp.CipherSuite;
import com.squareup.okhttp.ConnectionSpec;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import com.squareup.okhttp.TlsVersion;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String httpUrl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/retail/merchant/v1/invoices/";
    String jsonContent = "{'test':'test'}";

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonContent);
    Request request =  new Request.Builder().url(httpUrl).post(requestBody).build();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    okHttpClient.setConnectionSpecs(createConnectionSpecs(okHttpClient));

    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

    System.out.println(response.body());
}

  private static List<ConnectionSpec> createConnectionSpecs(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)  
        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
        .cipherSuites(
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
        .build();
    return Collections.singletonList(spec);
  }

}
```

I'm using these option on run of the application...

```
jdk1.7.0_80_64x\bin\java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake
```

Debug output gives....

```
    adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Issuer:  CN=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA II, OU=TC TrustCenter Class 2 CA, O=TC TrustCenter GmbH, C=DE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2e6a000100021fd752212c115c3b
  Valid from Thu Jan 12 14:38:43 GMT 2006 until Wed Dec 31 22:59:59 GMT 2025

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownServiceException: 
Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[TLSv1]
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.ConnectionSpecSelector.configureSecureSocket(ConnectionSpecSelector.java:73)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:185)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
        at com.jeff.Tester.main(Tester.java:29)
```

I can see that it says 'Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA', but I've listed that in the cipher suite.

Can anyone help me out please.

Comment: Run with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake and attach the output

Comment: What Java runtime do you use (type and version)? On some OpenJDK installations elleptic curve crypto is not available. Hence all EC ciphers are not supported and can not be enabled. And on Oracle JRE you need to install the unlimited strength policy to enable AES256.

Comment: what are you using for running your war/jar? Tomcat? I had similar case I was using tomcat 7 switched to tomcat 8 and issue was fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing

ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS) to 
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)

Fixes the issue.
(Or using JDK 8, or importing policy files, or using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA cipher)

```
package com.jeff;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.squareup.okhttp.CipherSuite;
import com.squareup.okhttp.ConnectionSpec;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;
import com.squareup.okhttp.TlsVersion;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String httpUrl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/retail/merchant/v1/invoices/";
        String jsonContent = "{'test':'test'}";

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonContent);
        Request request =  new Request.Builder().url(httpUrl).post(requestBody).build();
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        okHttpClient.setConnectionSpecs(createConnectionSpecs(okHttpClient));

        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        System.out.println(response.body());
    }

      private static List<ConnectionSpec> createConnectionSpecs(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)  
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .cipherSuites(
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
            .build();
        return Collections.singletonList(spec);
      }

}
```

Comment: Using @jeff-porter suggestion gives me the following error:

`java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES _128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, ........], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]`

I have enabled TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 using javacpl.exe tool for the java 7 version that I am using. Why does it still say supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]?

Comment: @PiyushKhera Have you found any solution about this problem?